# Conditional check for webkit speech recognition support

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, webkit, speech-recognition

I've got a search form that uses the Webkit speech recognition API. I'd like to serve a different form for browsers that don't support the API.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * Generate custom search form
 *
 * @param string $form Form HTML.
 * @return string Modified form HTML. */
add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', 'my_search_form', 10, 4);
function my_search_form( $form ) {
  if (!('someConditional)) {
      $form = '<form id="my-search" itemscope itemprop="potentialAction" itemtype="https://schema.org/SearchAction" method="get" action="https://mercury.photo/">
      <div class="speech">
        <label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="s">Search …</label><input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search …" />
        <span id="search-mic"><i class="fas fa-search-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
    </form>';

  } else { 
    $form = '<form id="my-voice-search" class="fubar" itemscope itemprop="potentialAction" itemtype="https://schema.org/SearchAction" method="get" action="https://mercury.photo/">
      <div class="speech">
        <label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="s">Search (type or speak) …</label><input type="text" name="s" id="transcript" placeholder="Search (type or speak) …" />
        <span id="search-mic" onclick="startDictation()"><i class="fas fa-microphone-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
    </form>';
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Is there a reliable way in PHP to check for Webkit speech recognition support?

Comment: Aside from nasty version-based detection, no. Feature support for this can only be determined client-side. So you'll need some JS to find that out and pass it to the server for the server to find out.

Comment: Yeah, I came to that conclusion. Wrestling with adding a body class but that's a different question; I'll post in the proper forum.

Comment: @John Ellmore If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.